# How can I update data with google appengine-python-ndb?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I have a User table and there is two fields. I want to update one field every day. How can I do this?
My codes:

```
class User(ndb.Model):
    username = ndb.StringProperty()
    something = ndb.StringProperty(repeated=True)
    created_date = ndb.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_date = ndb.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)
```

I want to change something field but how can I do this ?

Comment: You need to change the way you think about the data store, you don't have tables you have entities, you fetch individual entities and the update the properties of the entity then you write (put) the entity.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean manually and not automathic, just like this:

```
#Assuming you already know the key of the entity you want to change. 

user = user_key.get()        
user.something = 'new something'    
user.put()
```

Comment: Well, you need to know what entity to update, right? If you know the entity use it directly instead of getting it from the key.

Comment: How can I get user = user_key.get()

Comment: Taken from [app engine help](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/entities#Python_Retrieving_an_entity):
_To retrieve an entity identified by a given key, pass the Key object as an argument to the db.get() function. You can generate the Key object using the class method Key.from_path(). The complete path is a sequence of entities in the ancestor path, with each entity represented by its kind (a string) followed by its identifier (key name or numeric ID)_

Answer (score 1):

If you want to go through *all* of your `User` objects, you could do something like this:

```
for user in User.query():
    user.updated_date = datetime.datetime.now()
    user.put()
```

This is pretty slow but it will do the job as long as you don't have many users.
If you want to update all of your `User` objects every day, you probably want to look into [cron](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/cron) and [MapReduce](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/dataprocessing/).